# WARNING: On macOS, drake-visualizer is deprecated and will be removed from Drake on or after 2022-04-ˊ ˇ ˋ

Tags: drake

I see a warning about drake-visualizer on macOS will be deprecated. Could you tell me the new visualizer method? If possible, could you kindly provide a simple execution sample?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see a warning about drake-visualizer on macOS will be deprecated.

Yes, issue [#16215](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/16215) explains the background.

> Could you tell me the new visualizer method?

Call the function [pydrake.geometry.MeshcatVisualizerCpp.AddToBuilder](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.geometry.html#pydrake.geometry.MeshcatVisualizerCpp_.MeshcatVisualizerCpp_%5Bfloat%5D.AddToBuilder) to add it to your diagram.  When you start your program, it will print a URL to the console where you can open a web browser to view it.

> If possible, could you kindly provide a simple execution sample?

You can run [drake/tutorials/rendering_multibody_plant.ipynb](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/tutorials/rendering_multibody_plant.ipynb) locally to see  a demo.